# Login Form Not Working Correctly it keeps redirecting to the same page when the users try to access their account

Tags: laravel, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have an issue with my login form where when I press the login button, the web app just redirects me to the same page. This is first time I'm making a custom login form so it's a little complex for me as I used laravel/ui in my first project. I think the problem is that the model cannot directly access the users table that's in the db. I've linked the user model to the controller but that doesn't help. If anyone can take their time to show me how to connect the login form to the users table or tell me what's wrong with my code. Here's the code that I've written so far for the login.

**Login Form**

```
<form method="post" action="/login" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <div class="col-md-12 mt-md-0 mt-3">
        <label for="email" id="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" required>
        @error('email')<p class="text-danger"><small>{{$message}}</small></p> @enderror
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12 mt-md-0 mt-3">
        <label for="password" id="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control"  placeholder="Password"required>
        @error('password')<p class="text-danger"><small>{{$message}}</small></p> @enderror
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-4 w-50 py-2 fw-bold" >Login</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Routes**

```
Route::get('login', [SessionsController::class, 'create'])->middleware('guest');
Route::post('login', [SessionsController::class, 'store'])->middleware('guest');
```

**SessionsController**

```
public function store()
{
    $attributes = request()->validate([
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required'
    ]);

    if (! auth()->attempt($attributes)) {
        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            'email' => 'Your provided credentials could not be verified.'
        ]);
    }

    session()->regenerate();

    return redirect('/')->with('success', 'Welcome');
}
```

I think the problem is that this form is not retrieving the data from the db that's being stored when the user registers an account.

Comment: why are you using `multipart/form-data` for a login form? btw ... is the user's password hashed in the database?

Comment: Yes. The user password is hashed on the db.

Comment: is it displaying the error messages at all? it could be that sessions aren't working and they do get logged in but on redirect the auth middleware is then redirecting them back to the login page or login is failing but without the session working there would be no error messages to display

Comment: Yes. It's displaying the error below the email input.

Comment: what error is it displaying? and what type and size did you make the `password` field on the `users` table?

Comment: It's displaying 'Your provided credentials could not be verified.'. The type is varchar and the size is 255

Comment: then either the email doesn't match or the password isn't correct

Comment: The email and the password are automatically saved by the browser. When I click the input field, they are automatically filled in.

Comment: fill them in yourself to make sure (you are trying to diagnose something, remove as many variable as possible; make no assumptions) ... and what version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Ok. I'm using laravel 8 the latest version.

Comment: if you are still having an issue i would check to make sure the password wasn't double hashed (you hashed it manually but also have a mutator on the Model that is hashing the password attribute)

Comment: I think it was double hashed. Cause it appears two times. One it the User model and one in the controller. Let me look at it.

Comment: Remove the one from the register controller, but it still doesn't work. Although when I register a new user, the user is logged in into the system.